# Visual Studio 2019 Не удаеться запустить программу. Отказано в доступе

Tags: c++, git, github, visual-studio-2017

Остальные проекты в решении работают нормально, в свойствах конфигурации специально поставил запуск конкретного проекта для отладки. Если запустить все сразу ошибка появиться но остальные проекты откроются.
Также хотелось узнать что за знаки стоп или как они подписаны - "Пропущено" и чем они грозят?
Проект был взят с GitHub, установлен по документации, Visual Studio запущена в режиме прав администратора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: классика CMake. Когда генерируется проект, CMake иногда не выставляет проект, который нужно запустить. И пытается запустить папку. Да да, папку. Что делать? выберите справа проект, который Вы хотите запустить, в меню правой выберите "Set as sturtup project". и не запускайте студию с правами админа, делайте если только это действительно нужно

Comment: проблема была решена но костыльным образом, я просто отключил запуск ALL_BUILD, и теперь элементы открываются без данной папки. Спасибо!